# How to clip UIImageView in different shape

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, shapes, clip

Hi all :
         I create a UIImageView with my photo on my iphone screen just now, its shape is rectangle. and I want to clip the UIImageView into the shape of diamond. if there is any part of my photo beyond the diamond area, don't display it.
But now I don't quirt understand how to do it, so I'm ask for help. thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You try to add mask to your image using method below and put it to UIImageView

```
+ (UIImage *)image:(UIImage *)img withMask:(UIImage *)maskImg {
CGImageRef maskRef = maskImg.CGImage; 

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(img.CGImage, mask);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
CGImageRelease(mask);
CGImageRelease(masked);
return image;
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much! this is a great way to solve the problem. and I think if we can cut down the four corners of the rectangle UIImageView